# Get (and delete) GitLab CI environments more than 30 days old

Tags: json, gitlab, gitlab-ci, jq

I'm trying to delete old environments (eg, more than 30 days old) using [GitLab's API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#delete-an-environment). I have a working script; however, I can't seem to replace the "filter date" with an dynamic date, for example "30 days ago".

```yaml
delete-environments:
  before_script:
    - apk add --update curl jq coreutils && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
  script:
    - FILTER_DATE=$(date -d '2024-01-26T20:00:58.531Z' +%s)
    - echo $FILTER_DATE
    - OLD_ENVIRONMENTS=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${ENVIRONMENT_DELETER}" "https://gitlab.mycompany.net/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/environments?states=stopped" | jq '[.[] | select(.updated_at | .[0:19] +"Z" | fromdateiso8601 < 1706299258)]')
    - echo $OLD_ENVIRONMENTS
```

That works, but as soon as I try to replace `1706299258` with `$FILTER_DATE`...

```
    - OLD_ENVIRONMENTS=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${ENVIRONMENT_DELETER}" "https://gitlab.mycompany.net/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/environments?states=stopped" | jq '[.[] | select(.updated_at | .[0:19] +"Z" | fromdateiso8601 < $FILTER_DATE)]')
```

I get this error:

```
jq: error: $FILTER_DATE is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
[.[] | select(.updated_at | .[0:19] +"Z" | fromdateiso8601 < $FILTER_DATE)]
jq: 1 compile error
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

I've tried all kinds of quoting schemas around `$FILTER_DATE`, but I just can't seem to get the syntax right. Help!

Comment: Import the value like so: `jq --argjson FILTER_DATE "$FILTER_DATE" '… fromdateiso8601 < $FILTER_DATE …'`

Comment: @pmf -- Thank you! I saw `--arg` in the `jq` manual, and it didn't work, so I got fed up and posted here without seeing/trying `--argjson`

Comment: `--arg` would import the value as string, whereas `--argjson` interprets it as JSON. Since the value in question only consists of digits, it is interpreted as a number, and can be compared to the evaluated `fromdateiso8601` using `<`.